# Image Manipulation Filter like white Balance, Exposure, split Tone etc on IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have been trying since one week to achieve some image manipulation filters like WHITE BALANCE, EXPOSURE and SPLIT TONING (as in Photoshop) for my IOS app, but I didn't get a standard implementation to achieve any of them.

I found the shell scripts to achieve them through [ImageMagick](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/whitebalance/index.php)

but don't know how to change these scripts to its equivalent in C or objective C.
I simply uses some convert command to do the magic things.

Thanks in advance. Please Help.

White Balance is achievable through changing temperature and tint of the image also. so if someone out there knows how to manipulate these tint and temperature of image, please help me out of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the author of [ios-image-filters](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters), I can tell you that our project has a levels method that you can use to modify white balance. It is implemented as a category on UIImage and mimics Photoshop filters, so calling it is as straightforward as:

```
[self.imageView.image levels:0 mid:128 white:255];
```

Moreover, it's compatible with iOS 3 & 4, not just iOS 5. It's open source and has no dependencies, so it should be easy to modify if you don't find the filter you need.

Comment: I take this opportunity to really thank you for posting such a wonderful image manipulation sample project. Thanks indeed!

Comment: I have already gone through it. Your suggestion of using levels to achieve WhiteBalance doesn't seem to give results. I need it to be adjustable one. I tried different range of values but don't its giving good result. Can you suggest me about that?? Also what about exposure? Thanks Again.

Comment: Hi, esilver. Ok, I did some changes in code.'code' [self setSliderMin:64.0 Max:128.0 Value:64.0]; (custom function to configure slider) 'code' self.imageView.image = [image levels:0 mid:(192.0 - value) white:255]; 
The results I got is more like EXPOSURE rather than WHITEBALANCE.
Now I've got confused a little bit about what actually I'm achieving by that. Please explain.
Thanks.

Comment: Based on my understanding of photoshop and image manipulation, to modify the "white balance" you are essentially mapping one color value in the original image to pure white, and then a uniform mapping is applied to all colors between 0 and the color you chose. The curves filter allows you to create non-uniform mappings. It took me a while of experimenting with levels and curves in Photoshop, and then writing the corresponding code, before I had an intuitive grasp of this relationship. Good luck!

Answer (score 14):

Starting with iOS 5, [Core Image filters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH203-TPXREF101) are available.

A very simplified example, assuming you have added a UIImageView IBOutlet named imageView in Interface Builder, and set it up with an image file.

1. Add the CoreImage framework.
2. `#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>`
3. In `viewDidLoad`, add the following:

   ```
   CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:self.imageView.image];
   CIFilter *exposureAdjustmentFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIExposureAdjust"];
   [exposureAdjustmentFilter setDefaults];
   [exposureAdjustmentFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
   [exposureAdjustmentFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f] forKey:@"inputEV"];
   CIImage *outputImage = [exposureAdjustmentFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
   CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
   self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]];
   ```

Another option might be to use the filters from the GitHub [ios-image-filters](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters) project.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response indeed. I had already gone through the apple documentation for the CoreImage and am excited that finally it is available on IOS. But unfortunately my current app is on IOS 4 and I'm not left with option to upgrage.  Please help if you can direct me to some stuff in this regard without CoreImage. Thanks again.