# How to change the brightness and contrast of an UIImage in iOS6

Tags: iphone

How to change the brightness and contrast of an UIImage in iOS6?

Comment: Check out a similar post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920015/image-manipulation-filter-like-white-balance-exposure-split-tone-etc-on-ios

Comment: There is an open source project that allows you to accomplish this:
http://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters

Comment: In particular, check out the 2nd answer in the above question.

Comment: Here look this is apple demo code and it'll working fast, may be important for you.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html