# UIImage - Adjust image with temperature

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I'm trying to adjust the temperature of an image ie. warmer (more yellow) or colder (more blue). I haven't been able to find any solutions on the internet. I can already adjust the brightness, contrast and saturation of a UIImage using sliders, and I'd like to be able to adjust the temperature also using a slider, much the same way photoshop and lightroom do it.

Does anybody have any guidance as to how a temperature adjustment might be achieved?

Comment: If you have Photoshop at you hand, why not just experiement a bit with an image? You can measure one pixel, apply the color correction and measure the pixel again. That should give you an idea what Photoshop does to the rgb values. Then just pack that into some formula which probably is just some adding/substraction to the rgb values and apply that to the pixels in the ulimage.

Comment: @KaiMattern I was hoping to avoid having to do it on a pixel by pixel basis. I'm looking at the Core Image library, but I'm unsure of how to use it for temperature.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920015/image-manipulation-filter-like-white-balance-exposure-split-tone-etc-on-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check CITemperatureAndTint in the Apple documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CITemperatureAndTint

Alternatively, this library might help you as well:

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters

Comment: I've managed to get CITemperatureAndTint working the way I wanted it to, thanks.